# What is the best workaround for jQuery.html() removing double spaces on IE7 and IE8

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose you have code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery.html() - bug on IE7 and IE8</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#list").html('<li>List  item  with  double  spaces.</li>');
            console.log("Does inner html contain double space? ", $("#list").html().indexOf("  ") != -1);
            console.log("Binded HTML:", $("#list").html());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

On IE9, FF, Chrome works fine (binds html with double codes), but on IE7 and IE8 I get double spaces converted to one space. Compare console output on different browsers.

I can't use jQuery.text() instead because I have to use html content.

Have you faced such bug? What workaround you used?

Comment: Use regular expression to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Even with a regular expression (like `/\s\s+/g`), as you said, in IE double spaces are converted to one space using html().

You have to work with the original content like that :

```
var content='<li>List  item  with  double  spaces.</li>';
$("#list").html(content);
console.log("Does inner html contain double space? ", content.indexOf("  ") != -1);
```